# Git status has a bunch of irrelevant files

Tags: git

This has been driving me crazy, and I'm not sure how to approach it without creating an entirely different repository. I have a live website on `branchA` using `master` branch, and I want to completely rewrite the website, thus I want to push the new code onto `branchB`. Here are the steps I do:

```
git checkout -b branchB
git add -u
git commit -m "Why isn't this working"
git push origin branchB
```

And God knows why, it keeps adding these local files that I don't want into the commit and now I have these irrelevant files in my branch. I tried to `git add` each individual files in that folder too.

Can someone walk me through this? I've been on this for two nights now.

Comment: You should use a `.gitignore`

Comment: sorry, can you describe more clearly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will be to use a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

In the root directory of your Git repository, make a file called .gitignore

```
touch .gitignore
```

Then open the file with notepad (or a text editor of choice), and add the names of files you do not wish for Git to see. There are several [community created .gitignore files](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for various project types as well.

It is also notable that a gitignore file can use wildcards. I suggest you read up some gitignore documentation on the subject.